# Child Classes inheriting included module method from parent classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I am taking a class and they have given me my first attempt at using a module in ruby for a "Bank Account" program.

Here is the question..

> Create a module called Interest. Interest should have a method calculate_interest(balance, months, interest_amount) that sets the new balance of the account. It multiples the number of months that have accrued by the interest amount, adds it to the balance, and returns the new balance.
>
> Let's also create a method compound_interest that takes no parameters. Both SavingsAccount and CheckingAccount should implement compound_interest. Interest on a CheckingAccount is $10 each month and accrues every three months. Interest on a SavingsAccount is $5 each month and accrues every six months. Use Interest.calculate_interest in your compound_interest methods to set the new balance on the account.

Then I am given this code...

```
module Interest
end

class BankAccount
  include Interest
end

class CheckingAccount < BankAccount
end

class SavingsAccount < BankAccount
end
```

I have been trying for hours to figure out why I can't get it to work.
Here is what I have so far.

```
module Interest
  def calculate_interest(balance, months, interest_amount)
    balance += (months*interest_amount)
    balance
  end
end

class BankAccount
  attr_accessor :balance

  include Interest

  def initialize(balance)
    @balance = balance
  end
end

class CheckingAccount < BankAccount
  def initialize(balance)
    super(balance)
  end

  def compound_interest
    balance = Interest.calculate_interest(balance, 3, 10)
    balance
  end
end

class SavingsAccount < BankAccount
  def initialize(balance)
    super(balance)
  end

  def compound_interest
    balance = Interest.calculate_interest(balance, 6, 5)
    balance
  end

end
```

I am very new to this so I'm sure my code is pretty basic, please excuse that.
Anyway I keep getting this error...

```
NoMethodError
undefined method `calculate_interest' for Interest:Module
exercise.rb:24:in `compound_interest'

exercise_spec.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

If my child classes are inheriting the module method, I don't understand how the module method can't be found when called on them.

For further reference here are the specs

```
    describe BankAccount do
  describe "initialization" do
    it "takes an initial balance" do
      acc = BankAccount.new(283)
      expect(acc.balance).to eq(283)
    end
  end

  describe "#new" do
    it "returns the balance" do
      acc = BankAccount.new(283)
      expect(acc.balance).to eq(283)
    end
  end
end

describe CheckingAccount do
  it "has BankAccount as its parent class" do
    expect(CheckingAccount.superclass).to eq(BankAccount)
  end

  it "includes the module Interest" do
    expect(CheckingAccount.ancestors).to include(Interest)
  end

  describe "#compound_interest" do
    it "compounds the balance by the specified interest rate" do
      acc = CheckingAccount.new(283)
      new_balance = acc.compound_interest
      expect(new_balance).to eq(283 + 3 * 10)
      end
  end
end

describe SavingsAccount do
  it "has BankAccount as its parent class" do
    expect(SavingsAccount.superclass).to eq(BankAccount)
  end

  it "includes the module Interest" do
    expect(SavingsAccount.ancestors).to include(Interest)
  end

  describe "#compound_interest" do
    it "compounds the balance by the specified interest rate" do
      acc = SavingsAccount.new(283)
      new_balance = acc.compound_interest
      expect(new_balance).to eq (283 + 6 * 5)
    end
  end
end
```

Sorry for being so lengthy, I just want to give you the same information I have.

Comment: Hint: what object are the specs calling `compound_interest` on? What object are *you* calling `compound_interest` on? What is the class of the object you are calling `compound_interest` on? Does that class or any of its ancestors have a `compound_interest` method?

Comment: Unfortunately, "lengthy" is not the same as "specific", quite the opposite, in fact. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is a lot of extraneous fluff in your question that is irrelevant to the problem at hand and makes it hard to see where the *actual* problem is. (I only stumbled across it by luck.)

Comment: You lost me. I don't really understand the specs either.

Comment: Okay, so, the error message says that the error occurs on line 24 of `exercise.rb`, where you are calling a method named `compound_interest` on an object which doesn't know how to respond to that method. What object are you calling `compound_interest` on in that line? What is the class of that object? Does that class or any of its ancestors (i.e. its superclasses, its included modules, its superclasses' included modules) have a `compound_interest` method?

Comment: I am not calling compound_interest. There are two compound_interest methods in each child class. The spec calls those methods. Those methods call calculate_interest method inside the Interest module. The two child classes inherit the included method from the parent. I have been searching for a comparable problem online but I haven't found one yet. Like I said, I just learned about modules today so I haven't really had enough time for it to sink in. I usually get that "Aha Moment" after a while. Eventually it will click. Thanks for the help. I'm just stuck for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this entry (and the other point where `calculate_interest` is called)...

```
balance = Interest.calculate_interest(balance, 3, 10)
```

This is trying to call a method, belonging to `Interest` module.

...but there's no such method. In fact, `calculate_interest` was included in your classes via the module and became an `instance` method (a method belonging to every instance of the class).

The correct way to call it from within another instance method is without a receiver

```
balance = calculate_interest(balance, 3, 10)
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused because the instructions tell me to use `Interest.calculate_interest` in those methods. I tried that solution and it still fails with a new error.
  `` `  NoMethodError`
   ` undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass```

Comment: Yes, congratulations, you got past the first error!  It seems that `balance` contains nil so you can't add a number to it.  Try referencing the attr_accessor` method instead of creating a local variable. `self.balance = calculate_interest(self.balance, 3, 10)`

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to use the @balance instance variable instead of "balance" in the module method. Along with your advice made it work. Thanks!

Comment: "Use Interest.calculate_interest in your compound_interest methods to set the new balance on the account." That is literally in the instructions. It's like they were stumping me on purpose.

Comment: `self.balance` would work as well as `@balance` but in any case glad it's working for you.